# Union with Group By

Tags: sql, group-by, union

Had a look at other questions, tried different things but still returning more than one row.

Problem with Union on 2 tables, with group by clause. There should only be one row returned, grouped by the serviceID.

```
 SELECT 
    serviceID, 
    serviceName, 
    FullCount,
    WaitingCount,
    InProgressCount
    from (

    select
    a.serviceID,
    serviceName,
    count(applicantID) FullCount,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS WaitingCount,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS InProgressCount
    from Products s
    left join Assigns a on a.serviceID = s.productID 
    WHERE s.clientID = @ClientID
    group by serviceID, serviceName

    UNION

    select
    s.serviceID,
    p.serviceName,
    count(s.ApplicantID) FullCount,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN s.status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS WaitingCount,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN s.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS InProgressCount
    from Legacies s
    Left Join Products p on s.serviceID = p.productID 
    WHERE s.client = @CompanyName
    group by serviceID, serviceName

    ) t
    GROUP BY serviceID, serviceName
```

I'm always getting 2 rows returned, one from each of the tables. I need to group them both together so it only returns 1 row, based on the servicedID.

The data I'm trying to return is from the following tables..

**Products Table**

```
productID    serviceName  
-------------------------
    1        Gold Service
    2        Silver Service
    3        Bronze Service
```

**Assigns Table**

```
ApplicantID    serviceID    status
-------------------------------------  
     1             1           0
     2             1           0
     3             1           1
     4             2           0
     5             1           1
```

**Legacies Table**

```
ApplicantID    serviceID    status
-------------------------------------  
     1             1           0
     2             1           0
     3             1           0
     4             2           0
     5             1           1
```

The result I'm trying to get is one row per serviceID, to show how many applicants are on this service in both the Legacies and Assigns table, something like:-

```
serviceID   serviceName  FullCount WaitingCount  InProgressCount
----------------------------------------------------------------
    1       Gold Service     8          5               3
    2       Silver Service   2          2               0
    3       Bronze Service   0          0               0
```

FullCount is a total number of applicants on each service, WaitingCount is the number of applicants on the service with a status of '0' and InProgressCount is the number on this service with a status of '1'

Comment: which column is different in the two rows in union

Comment: Post your actual query.  What you posted is not right.  You cannot select `fullcount` (amongst other columns) if it's not aggregated or in the `group by` clause.

Comment: I am surprise if this query execute.

Comment: @avery_larry: it's probably MySQL which allows such a nonsense and prefers to return random results instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on additional information, I think you can just `union all` the Legacies and Assigns tables.

**still untested**

```
select serviceID, servicename, count(*) fullcount
   ,sum(case when status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WaitingCount
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS InProgressCount
from (
   select ApplicantID, serviceID, status
   from Assigns
   WHERE clientID = @ClientID

   union all

   select ApplicantID, serviceID, status
   from Legacies
   WHERE clientID = @ClientID
) combined
left join Products P on P.productID = combined.serviceID
group by serviceID, servicename
```

**below is before edit**

It's hard to tell because you do not post enough information (no sample data, no table structures, no expected output).  But I think you can probably combine it all into 1 query:

**untested** which should be obvious with the lack of information.

```
SELECT isnull(a.serviceID, L.serviceID) serviceID, p.serviceName
    ,count(*) FullCount, SUM(CASE WHEN isnull(a.status, L.status) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WaitingCount
    ,sum(CASE WHEN isnull(a.status, L.status) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) InProgressCount
from Legacies L 
full outer join Assigns a on a.serviceID = L.serviceID
right outer join Products P on P.productID = isnull(a.serviceID, L.serviceID)
where (P.clientID = @ClientID
        or L.client = @CompanyName
    )
group by isnull(a.serviceID, L.serviceID), p.serviceName
```

Comment: Thanks - I've added more information now which makes it a little clearer

Comment: Works perfect, can see where I was going wrong now.